# Question about steepest descent

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I'm studying an optimization book and there's something I can't figure out. It's about the steepest descent method, but I think it's a question that is related to other methods as well. The book says

> Consider the ideal case, where the function is quadratic and the line searches are exact.

The function is $$ f(x) = \frac 12 x^T Q x - b^T x$$ where $Q$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Then it says that to compute the step length $a_{k}$ that minimizes $f(x_{k} - a\nabla f_{k})$, we differentiate this function $f(x_{k} - a\nabla f_{k})$ and we set the derivative to zero.

What I don't understand, if we do that, aren't we trying to find the minimizer? If yes, then why go to the trouble of having a line search method. We want to find the minimum of $f$, just differentiate, set equal to $0$ and find the min/max. If we have a method and in every step we set the $\nabla f$ equal to $0$, what are we doing exactly ? Finding all the minimums or ..?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In gradient descent, at each iteration you take a step in the direction of steepest descent. In other words, you take a step in the direction of the vector $-\nabla f(x_k)$. But how far should you step in that direction?

Comment: Yeah i know. Im just confused because in order to find that "how far", he differentiates the function with respect to $a_{k}$ and sets the derivative equal to $0$. Now that I think about it, this probably doesn't mean that he is finding the min of the function in general, because if he wanted to do that he would have to differentiate with respecto to $x$ ? Not sure..

Comment: In this example, at each iteration we choose the special step size which results in the greatest possible reduction in the value of $f$. In other words, the step size $a_k$ is chosen to be the scalar value which minimizes $f(x_k - a \nabla f(x_k))$. (Note that the step size changes from one iteration to the next.)

Comment: Exactly. That minimum function value we find, it is not the minimum value of the function in general, is it? If the function is convex (which it is in this case), it only has one global minimum. The minimum value we find by the differentiation you mentioned, isn't this minimum, it's just the min value the function can acquire in the specific direction we chose. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. That was my problem.. I was confused because I was thinking " How can we find minimum function values in each step, when our function has only 1 minimum.. ". I guess if we wanted to find the global min, we could differentiate with respect to $x$, but we don't choose that and we choose the line search in order to avoid multiple time consuming calculations.